# How do I loop a menu that has submenus in python?

Tags: python, loops, menu

I am trying to create a main menu with submenus.  I want to make it so that no matter what sequence the user chooses from main menu to submenus, they will be ultimately be directed back to the main menu--that is, until they choose the last option (3. hold and end turn).

This is where I am getting stuck.  Right now, the user can only go through the menu sequence once.  How do I make this a repeating loop?

```
#main menu
playermenumain=raw_input("What would you like to do?\n (1) Buy\n (2)Sell\n (3)Hold and end turn ")

if playermenumain=="1":

        buyermenu=raw_input("In what area would you like to buy?"\n (1)Stocks\n (2) Bonds\ (3) Nevermind\n)
        if buyermenu=="1":
            stockamount=stockamount+500
        elif buyermenu=="2":
            bondamount=bondamount+500
        else:
            buyermenu=raw_input("In what area would you like to buy?"\n (1)Stocks\n (2) Bonds\ (3) Nevermind\n) 

if playermenumain=="2":

    sellermenu=raw_input("In what area would you like to buy?"\n (1)Stocks\n (2) Bonds\ (3) Nevermind\n)
        if sellermenu=="1":
            stockamount=stockamount-500
        elif sellermenu=="2":
            bondamount=bondamount-500
        else:
            sellermenu=raw_input("In what area would you like to buy?"\n (1)Stocks\n (2) Bonds\ (3) Nevermind\n) 

if playermenumain=="3":

    break
#main menu loop: no matter what is selected, player is directed back to main menu until option 3 (end turn) is selected:

while playermenumain=="1" or playermenumain=="2":

        playermenumain=raw_input("What would you like to do?\n (1) Buy\n (2)Sell\n (3)Hold and end turn ")
        continue
```

Comment: What's going on in the arguments to `raw_input`? What you show doesn't look like valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a while True loop with a break instead of the while condition you have. For example:

```
def submenu_buy():
  # Put your submenus here
  pass

def submenu_sell():
  # Put your submenus here
  pass

while True:
  playermenumain=raw_input("What would you like to do?\n (1) Buy\n (2)Sell\n (3)Hold and end turn ")
  if playermenumain == "1":
    submenu_buy()
  elif playermenumain == "2":
    submenu_sell()
  elif playermenumain == "3":
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your main menu code in a method, and call that method in a loop.  Each submenu should be a method call as well, and should return when you go back to the previous menu.

You should look up basic method use and program flow; this is more of a general programming concept than a specific language question.  It is critical in almost everything you will do, so you should take your time to really understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Create a function menu() to a) display the menu, b) reject invalid response, and c) returns a valid response. This menu will remove redundancy in your code as you need it 3 times.
2. Move the selling logic into a separate function, let's call it sell()
3. Likewise, move the buying logic to buy()
4. Use underscore to make you identifiers (variables and function names) easier to read. I prefer 'main_menu_response' over 'playermenumain'

With these suggestions, my implementation is:

```
def menu(prompt, choices):
    print '\n\n{0}\n'.format(prompt)
    count = len(choices)
    for i in range(count):
        print '({0}) {1}'.format(i + 1, choices[i])
    response = 0
    while response < 1 or response > count:
        response = raw_input('    Type a number (1-{0}): '.format(count))
        if response.isdigit():
            response = int(response)
        else:
            response = 0
    return response

def buy(stockamount, bondamount):
    response = menu('What to buy?', ['Stocks', 'Bonds', 'Nevermind'])
    # Do something

def sell(stockamount, bondamount):
    response = menu('What to sell?', ['Stocks', 'Bonds', 'Nevermind'])
    # Do something

# ======================================================================
# Main program starts here
# ======================================================================
stockamount=10000
bondamount=10000

main_menu_response = 0
while main_menu_response != 3:
    main_menu_response = menu('What to do?', ['Buy', 'Sell', 'End'])
    if main_menu_response == 1:
        buy(stockamount, bondamount)
    elif main_menu_response == 2:
        sell(stockamount, bondamount)
```